# CodeIgniter Redirect on Heroku

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

I'm having some issues with CodeIgniter redirects on Heroku. Here is the URL:

http://sergei-game.herokuapp.com/

In particular, what is happening is that the redirects (/controller/function) are being appended to the URL rather than replacing /controller/function in the URL.

I do not have these issues when I navigate to the same URL on localhost.

Here is the relevant code in the main controller:

```
public function index() {
    redirect('gameplayer/login', 'refresh');
}

public function login() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        // if logged in, go to character selection page
        redirect('gameplayer/viewAccount');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('auth/login');
    }
}
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I took a look at the Heroku logs, but they don't make very much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the correct base URL configured in CodeIgniter. In the configuration file located at `application/config/config.php` find the line `$config['base_url']` and set it to your URL. In your case it should be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://sergei-game.herokuapp.com/';`

Comment: This fixes the issue. Why do you think CodeIgniter doesn't infer base_url when passed ''?